# Best practice for assets in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and was wondering where the best place is to store js/ css/ images/ etc? Typically I'm used to:

> ```
> /
> --/application
> --/system
> --/public
> ----/css
> ----/js
> ----/images
> ```

But what would be the best way to use such a directory structure? All that I've found in my research is that commonly codeigniter projects have their assets sitting next to the application and system folders.

Comment: When you say "best", you should clarify what your specific goals are. The structure you posted is fine, I'm not sure what your concern is - can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, isn't it dangerous to have the data on the root level of the directory structure? All that is protecting the key folders (e.g. system) from outsiders is a .htaccess. If this is fine, then by all means I'll keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well, isn't it dangerous to have the data on the root level of the directory structure? All that is protecting the key folders (e.g. system) from outsiders is a .htaccess

Assuming you're running Apache, `.htaccess` with `deny from all` should be fine.

If not, this is one reason why you usually see something like this at the beginning of each file:

```
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access.');
```

This ensures the script can't be accessed directly.

You may also be able to keep your application and system files below the web root, something like this:

```
htdocs
    application
    system
    public_html
        index.php
        public
            css
            js
            img...
```

Just use a relative path in index.php to define your CI paths:

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```