# How to organize structure of an Angular and CodeIgniter project

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm trying to build an app with CodeIgniter. I also want to build a CMS for the admin to manage all content. This means in my project I'm going to have some "public" and "admins" folders but I only want to use AngularJS for the CMS.

I've already built the public part and there's no Angular on it but my problem is now that i want to use AngularJS for the admin. I don't know how to structure my project for that.

This is how it was before I decided to implement the admin part with AngularJS in front-end

```
+application
    +controllers/
        +admin/
            -my admin controllers
        +public/
            -my public controllers
    +config/
    +views/
        +admin/
            -my admin views
        +public/
            -my public views
+assets
    +css
        +admin
            -my admin css
        +public
            -my public css
    +js
    +img
    +ect...
+system
```

Now that i want to build my CMS with AngularJS I wanted to create a folder called "ng" in the root and put all my "ng" files. It would be like:

```
+application // CI
+assets //js css img ect...
+ng // angular files
+system // CI core
```

Is this right? How it supposed to be?

Also, because I want to use Angular I'm gonna deal with the UI-router to load the views but I wanted to load the view with CI to check in the controller if the user is connected. If it's not, redirect him to the login page.

Comment: [crud tutorial with codeigniter and angular js](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/codeigniter-3-and-angularjs-crud-with-search-and-pagination-exampleexample.html) sample program

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your system and application source away from accessible from web which being said keep you source one level up from document root.  I recommend this.

```
+Application // CI
+System // CI System
-Public
    +CSS
    -JS
        +Angular
    +Images
```

Ref:
[Best practice for assets in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147569/best-practice-for-assets-in-codeigniter)